# Arranging buttons into diamond shape in android xml

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I would like to create a a screen with four buttons, each in the shape of a diamond (like a square turned 45 degrees to the side) and all four arranged into a larger diamond.

I've searched around here on SO and managed to create this xml file which sort of hints at what I want to achieve:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/White"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:visibility="visible">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/scoreCount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge">

</TextView>


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_weight="1.0" >


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/topLeftOuter"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height = "60dp"
        android:background="@color/Blue"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:rotation="45" >


    </Button>



</RelativeLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:clickable="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_weight="1.0" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bottomLeftOuter"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height = "60dp"
        android:background="@color/Yellow"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:rotation="45" >


    </Button>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_weight="1.0" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bottomRightOuter"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height = "60dp"
            android:background="@color/Red"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:rotation="45" >


        </Button>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:clickable="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_weight="1.0" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/topRightOuter"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height = "60dp"
            android:background="@color/Chartreuse"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:rotation="45" >


        </Button>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the result:

[image: This is the result]

But I would like something more along the lines of this:

[image]

How should I go about getting there?

Comment: You cannot achieve it using linear layout. Use relative layout.

Comment: When you'r using weight with vertical linearlayout then `height` must be `0dp` and if it is with horizontal then `width` must be a `0dp`. Also parent layout has a weight sum of your child views.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#fff"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:visibility="visible">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/scoreCount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>




<Button
    android:id="@+id/bottomRightOuter"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height = "90dp"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:rotation="45"
    android:layout_marginLeft="218dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="218dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/topLeftOuter"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height = "90dp"
    android:background="#0022ff"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:rotation="45"
    android:layout_marginBottom="67dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bottomRightOuter"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/topRightOuter"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/topRightOuter"/>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/topRightOuter"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:background="#00ff00"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:rotation="45"
    android:layout_marginTop="-23dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/topLeftOuter"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/bottomLeftOuter"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height = "90dp"
    android:background="#ffd000"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:rotation="45"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="78dp"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

the main point was that you needed to get rid of all those layouts

Comment: This makes sense and does the trick, similarly to the others answers.
I'm now curious if there is a way to set the size of these buttons in such a way that it would look the same on all screen sizes? 
I mean for example make the edges of the diamond touch the sides of the screen (or whichever end, height or width, is smaller) regardless f screen size? That was why I started pushing so many layouts in.

Comment: you can do that  but its alot of work.  you have to make alot of values folders, in those folders put a dimens.xml with the dimens with the wanted button size. this way android will pick the right size for the screen.  see this link for more info:https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: I see. I was hoping it would be a bit simpler. I experimented with the Java swing library in the past and there I tended to get the screen size parameters and define everything relative to that. Not something I can push into an xml I suppose, but is that still something that is done in android programming or is it discouraged? 
It seems to me like there is a large preference to define such things in xml and leaving only the logic for the code.

Comment: i agree imo there should be a %of screen option. yes i have a few preset layouts made but i rarely differ from those as it just takes somuch time to make it nice on all sizes.idd consider doing everything with layouts in xml, you CAN do it in programing but its a pain. good luck with your project

Answer (score 1):

You can use `relative` layout or `constraint` layout to achieve this shape. It is not possible with `linear` layout. Try the below code using `relative` layout (Adjust the margins if necessary):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/White"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="visible">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/scoreCount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge">

    </TextView>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bottomLeftOuter"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:rotation="45"
        android:visibility="visible">
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/topRightOuter"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomLeftOuter"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/bottomLeftOuter"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/bottomLeftOuter"
        android:layout_marginBottom="31dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:rotation="45"
        android:visibility="visible">
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bottomRightOuter"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:rotation="45"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/topRightOuter"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/scoreCount"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/scoreCount"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp">
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/topLeftOuter"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="31dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="#f93"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:rotation="45"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bottomRightOuter"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bottomRightOuter"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/bottomRightOuter"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/bottomRightOuter">
    </Button>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:src="@drawable/diamond"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="5dp"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:src="@drawable/diamond"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="5dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:src="@drawable/diamond"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:src="@drawable/diamond"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am coping and paste my project design code and do some of the changes in that so you can try this.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlMain"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
        <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnIDGun"
                        android:background="@drawable/round_button"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/btnSize_Width"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/btnSize_Height"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:rotation="45"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnIDGun"
                        android:background="@drawable/round_button"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/btnSize_Width"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/btnSize_Height"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:rotation="45"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
                </RelativeLayout>
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnDropLocation"
                        android:background="@drawable/round_button"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/btnSize_Width"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/btnSize_Height"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:rotation="45"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnParticipate"
                        android:background="@drawable/round_button"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/btnSize_Width"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/btnSize_Height"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:rotation="45"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>


                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnDonate"
                        android:background="@drawable/round_button"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/btnSize_Width"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/btnSize_Height"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:rotation="45"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>


                </RelativeLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:rotation="45">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/orange"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
            android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```